# Java Logger not maintaining between classes

Tags: java, logging

After referencing the following:
[Java logging through multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737880/java-logging-through-multiple-classes)

[Passing a logger between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915778/passing-a-logger-between-classes)

[java logger to one file over several classes and packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910410/java-logger-to-one-file-over-several-classes-and-packages)

I still have the following issue:

I'm using the following logging mechanics:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");

FileHandler debugFileHandler = null;
    try {debugFileHandler = new FileHandler("DebugFile.txt");} 
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    logger.addHandler(debugFileHandler);
    debugFileHandler.setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
    debugFileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

and am writing to the specified file correctly with multiple classes (within the same and different packages/subpackages) using the following:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
logger.log(Level.FINE,"[SYSTEM] This is text...")
```

However, there are other classes which fail to write to the text file. I confirmed the classes were indeed logging by using:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO,"[SYSTEM] This is text...")
```

which outputted the text to the terminal due to a ConsoleHandler I'm using, but not to the file. Any hints to the issue? Thanks! :)

Comment: Some class log and some don't? What are the differences between these classes? Do they come from the same class loader? Are you sure they log AFTER you've set up your handler?